# Faulty border lines around SAPUI5 BusyIndicator

Tags: sapui5, busyindicator

There is an extra border around the `BuysIndicator` with the new version of SAPUI5. Any trick to remove it using CSS or something else?

[image: BusyIndicator with unwanted border]

Comment: Don't use the latest version but one that works?

Comment: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js for the latest **stable** version as of Nov 2018 **1.58.4**

Comment: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.58.4/resources/sap-ui-core.js for a **specific version** that doesn't change every other day.

Comment: Seems like you're using the version 1.56 as it's only reproducible there. In the current stable version (1.58.5), the native outline is gone. You can [ask to downport the fix](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/new) to the 1.56 line as it's still maintained till 2019.